# IOS App crashes, but there is no crash log available

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I am starting my App from XCode and with a specific behaviour it just disconnects and the app disappears from my IPAD screens. 
So I guess the app crashes.

Now my question. Where Do I get this crashlog ? I already looked into 
Window -> Devices -> choose my Ipad -> "View Device Logs" . But I cant see any actual crash log. I have some from earlier times, but my actual doesn't show up.

How do I get a crashlog ?

Comment: The app may have run out of memory. You don't get a crash log if the app runs out of memory. Run it in Instruments to see whether the memory usage is growing rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

check if you have enabled Share with app developers option in settings.  Privacy -> Analytics -> Share with App Developers.Xcode was not showing crash logs, enabling this helped me

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the device console under windows, devices in Xcode.

Its possibly saying something about code signing, bundle id's or missing libraries.

Comment: Can you please read my question again ? Is there a different how I do this ? Because I do not understand your answer. The question is how to get the crash log. Not how to solve the issue.

Comment: Its not a code signing issue ? It crashes only in a specific funtion.

Comment: You're right, we didn't fully understand your question the first time. Even so, check what is on the console when it crashes, it might give a clue

Comment: Nothing on the console. Even if there is something. I am interested to know where is the crashlog. The question is not how to solve the issue. If I would know, how to get the crashlog it would help in general.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the crash logs from "earlier times".

You have maximum amount of saved crash logs, and if you passed it - you won't see the new crash logs

Comment: I already deleted crashlogs, so I see only 10 entries. But nothing. I see some new crashlogs, but from searchd.